# Service Account Authentication Warning After Enabling 'setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled'

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

## Issue

After updating my AppEngine hosted app's **Date** objects to **Timestamp** objects per the Firebase **Timestamp** warning and enabling `setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled` a new warning regarding using a service auth account is displaying.

However, I am currently using a service auth account when initializing Firebase per the documentation under the section [Initialize Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize) sub-section *initialize on your own server*. The app works as expected despite the *new* warning message.

### Original 'setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled' Warning

> The behavior for java.util.Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
>   To hide this warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to add the following code to your app before calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:
>
> ```
> FirestoreOptions options = FirestoreOptions.newBuilder().setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true).build();
> Firestore firestore = options.getService();
> ```
>
> With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read back as com.google.cloud.Timestamp objects instead of as system java.util.Date objects. So you will also need to update code expecting a java.util.Date to instead expect a Timestamp. For example:
>
> ```
> // Old:
> java.util.Date date = (java.util.Date) 
> snapshot.get("created_at");
> // New:
> Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp) 
> snapshot.get("created_at");
> java.util.Date date = timestamp.toDate();
> ```
>
> Please audit all existing usages of java.util.Date when you enable the new behavior. In a future release, the behavior will be changed to the new behavior, so if you do not follow these steps, YOUR APP MAY BREAK.

### New Service Account Authentication Warning

> Dec 09, 2018 12:54:39 PM com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider warnAboutProblematicCredentials
>   WARNING: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.

## Setup

**Initializing Firebase**

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredentials(
        fromStream(Gson().toJson(FirebaseCredentialsHelper.get()).byteInputStream()))
    .setFirestoreOptions(FirestoreOptions.newBuilder()
    .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true).build())
    .build())
```

**Service Credentials Object**

The *FirebaseCredentialsHelper* returns the service account credentials depending on if the app is built in *Staging* or *Production* mode.

```
return FirebaseCredentials(
                "service_account",
                "[project-id]",
                "[private-key-id]",
                "[private-key]",
                "[client-email]",
                "[client-id]",
                "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
                "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
                "[client-x509-cert-url]"
        )
```